# htaccess redirect is not working with [R=301,L]

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I did the changes to my web site to change the dynamic url to SEO friendly url. I have added the following rewrite rule to my .htaccess file for 301 redirection.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+business\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)&subcat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ business.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

but when i typed seo friendly url in the browser it is redirecting back to the old url.

anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `R=301` back to original URI.

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+abc\.php\?products=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ products/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^products/([\w-]+)/?$ abc.php?products=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+business\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)&subcat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Software&Tools/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ business.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @anubhava. rewrite rule is working with type [QSA,L,NC], but how the search engines will recognize the 301 pages if did not specified the type [R=301,L]?. Becuase there is already some of the old dynamic url's listed on search engines, so i want to create the 301 pages for old url's.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. it is working for 301 redirection now. i tried it for multiple parameters but it is not working for redirection. can you please suggest what is the wrong i am doing. refer the rules below:                                                  RewriteBase /                                                RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+business\.php\?cat=([^&]*)&subcat=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ business.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

Comment: Hmm cant read code from comments, can you edit your question and post it there.

Comment: RewriteEngine on                                           RewriteBase /                                                RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+business\.php\?cat=([^&]*)&subcat=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Software&Tools/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ business.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

Comment: i have sent the code separately in previous reply. please refer it and provide your suggestion. Thanks in advance anubhava.

Comment: I don't see any edit in your question. You need to edit your question and provide full .htaccess code there otherwise I can't read your code from comments.

Comment: I have modified .htaccess code for multiple parameters in the url.

Comment: Thanks for your help @anubhava. the redirection is working perfect with the new code.

Comment: ok glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT FORMAT

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jaring\.poskopilkadapolri\.web\.id$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.jaring\.poskopilkadapolri\.web\.id$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/jaring\.poskopilkadapolri\.web\.id\/module\/home\/" [R=301,L]
```